# Applying NOT restriction to a regex pattern

Tags: regex, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I use `preg_replace_callback` with the pattern of

```
preg_replace_callback('/^(word1 .*),(.*)\./i',
function($m){
processing $m[1] and $m[2]
}, $str);
```

to match a sentence start with `word1`. How can I modify the pattern to make a restriction for the second word in the pattern?

The first match above should start with `word1` as long as `word2,word3,etc` are NOT the second word.

I do not want to alter `$m[1]` and `$m[2]`, just to match when `word2,word2,etc` are the second word in the string.

It should match,

```
word1 something, and more.
```

but not

```
word1 word2 something, and more.
word1 word3 something, and more.
```

Comment: I think you need `?!` (negative lookahead), as it is difficult to say what you exactly want without some test-cases

Comment: @rv7 I added some examples as you advised.

Comment: Edit your question and show us what the replacement looks like.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry, I had to include the full code in the first place. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match lines which begin with `word1`, but `word2` and `word3` do not occur anywhere else in the line, then you can try using a negative lookahead assertion:

```
^word1(?!.*\b(?:word2|word3)\b).*$
```

### Demo

The `(?!.*\b(?:word2|word3)\b)` term asserts that we do not see `word2` or `word3` as standalone words anywhere else in the remainder of the line.

Here is the actual PHP code:

```
preg_replace_callback('/^(word1(?!.*\b(?:word2|word3)\b).*),(.*)\./i',
    function($m) {
        # processing $m[1] and $m[2]
    }, $str);
```

Not much really changes in the above code, except that I inserted a negative lookahead to make sure that `word2` and `word3` do not occur.

Comment: @Nick You've been beating me out to many answers lately, about time I get on first base :-)

Comment: I don't know, you still seem to have got from 200k to 201k pretty fast! :-)

Comment: Thanks for this but I need `$1 and $2` matches for the function of `preg_replace_callback` not just matching the entire sentence. I just want to adjust `(word1 .*)` part.

Comment: @Googlebot Other than the tag, your actual question mentions nothing of this, hence neither does my answer.  Edit your question and show us what the expected output is of the 3 example strings.

Comment: Perfectly addressed my problem. One question, out of curiosity. Why do we need `\b`, as `^(word1 (?!.*(?:word2|word3)).*),(.*)\.` works well?

Comment: @Googlebot `\b` is a _word boundary_, which indicates that you _only_ want to match `word2` as a standalone word.  For example, `aword2s` would match to `word2` but not to `\bword2\b`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use: `^(word1\s(?!word2|word3).+)\,\s?(.+)$`

[**Demo**](https://regexr.com/41joh)

Comment: Valid answer, but I suspect that maybe `word2` and `word3` are just placeholders for some other actual words (which might not contain the string `word`, or have numbers in them).